# macOS Sierra 10.12 Printing Error

Tags: printing, macos, canon

Just upgraded 2012 mac mini to macOS Sierra 10.12.  Now when I try to print to a Canon MF-4500, I get an error message (filter failed).  I tried resetting the printing system and re-added the networked MF-4500 but I got same error message.

Comment: Are you in a position where you are able to plug the printer directly into the computer? If you can, try printing that way. Does that work?

Answer (score 1):

Canon say that they are working on a fix. In the meantime, [converting to a TIFF, removing the alpha channel and printing *that*](https://support.usa.canon.com/kb/index?page=content&id=ART166610) works. (Just checked and it works fine for me MP640.)